# Linq context object isn't registering as a type of System.IDisposable object

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, linq-to-sql, .net-4.0, interface

I'm trying to use my 'context' object in a using statement.  It works on one project, but on another, I'm getting the following error.

> '...': type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible
>   to 'System.IDisposable'

When I'm referring to the 'context' object, I'm referring to the object automatically created when you're working with LINQ to SQL.

The class I'm working within, implements another interface, could that be screwing up this context object?

```
using (TGDC context = new TGDC())
            {

            }
```

the word

> using

has the red squigly line under it (error).

Comment: It acts like you have more than one TGDC class declared.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You should add a reference to `System.Data.Linq`. I suspect that's the issue.

Comment: It didn't fix it for me. It seems I needed to add a reference to the EntityFramework assembly

Comment: Using `Entity Framework 6`, I had to add the reference to EntityFramework.dll as mentioned in the comment above.  Older versions of Entity Framework require different assemblies to be referenced to fix this issue.

Answer (score 8):

Or, if you are using Entity Framework, make sure you have a reference to `System.Data.Entity` and `System.Data.Objects` (C#: `using` / VB.NET: `Imports`).

Comment: adding a reference to System.Data.Entity fixed it for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Add a reference to the EntityFramework.dll assembly that is referenced by the project that defines your EF context class.

Comment: Worked for me using VS2013 Express.

Answer (score 3):

Add a reference to the EntityFramework assembly

Answer (score 1):

This is an older question, but since I found it via a Google search:

I've experienced this while working with a website that worked without issue in Visual Studio 2010.

There's something odd about Visual Studio 2012 and Entity Framework; adding EF to an existing project causes EF 5.0 to be installed (NuGet package), with no option to stick with 4.0.

A comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14474054/11912) to a linked question is what made the realization pop.

Solution seems to be upgrade to the EF version that VS 2012 uses, or use VS 2010.

Answer (score 0):

It says that `TGDC` does not implement the IDisposable interface.

How does the class declaration for TGDC look? Do you have more compiler errors? Do you have several classes named TGDC in different namespaces?

Answer (score 0):

I get this periodically and for a while I always used to struggle with it because its not immediately evident what's wrong.  Seems like all the hoops have been jumped through, but alas, not so.  Eventually the solution will stick.

In the project you are writing this code you are referencing the project in which your "TGDC" is defined but you are not referencing System.Data.Linq.  You need to reference both these assemblies.  This can only really happen when you are using some sort of a layered architecture.