# Why does the Using statement give an error even though my type implements IDisposable?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing

In my `DataAccess` project I have the code:

```
using (TandAEntities dataContext = new TandAEntities())
{
    // Some code
}
```

This gives no error and works fine.

But in my Unit Test project, I have that same code, but the compiler gives an error; type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to `'System.IDisposable'`

I checked the definition by pressing `F12`, and it does indeed implement `IDisposable`, and has a dispose method.

Am I perhaps missing some references?

Comment: Could you show the code of your unit test that is not compiling?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754021/linq-context-object-isnt-registering-as-a-type-of-system-idisposable-object

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Most likely answer in linked duplicate - missing `using System.Data.Linq`.

Other options: you have stale DLLs somewhere (i.e. installed in the GAC).

If you can't easily find stale DLL by just looking around and checking GAC - change code to something that uses this type but compiles and debug the test. Check Debug->Windows->Modules for location of the assembly with this type that is actually used.

Comment: I included using System.Data.Linq, and it did not work, but I then added a reference to EntityFramework, and then it worked.

Comment: The point is, to add all the necessary DLLs so that compiler can search through all of them to find a base class that can be converted to `IDisposable`. For example, `DataContext` class that implements `IDisposable` exists in EntityFramework dll.

Comment: For my case, after I add the System.Data.Linq references the error goes away